# ACPI Errors, I've been having this issue for a long time. Sometimes my PC won't run, but others yes

Tags: debian, acpi

I'm running debian 10 in an Asus TUF gaming laptop.

Sometimes when I select the kernel during GRUB, after that, I get for few seconds messages like this:

```
    [    0.365624] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.365628] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.366792] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.366797] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.366800] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.366803] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.366808] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.366811] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.367951] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.367956] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.367960] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.367963] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.367967] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.367971] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.367975] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.367980] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.367983] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.367986] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.367991] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.367994] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368036] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368041] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368044] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368047] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368052] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368055] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368094] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368099] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368102] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368105] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368109] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368113] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368152] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368156] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368160] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368163] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368167] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368170] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368209] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368214] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368217] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368220] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368225] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368228] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368267] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368271] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368275] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368278] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368282] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368285] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368324] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368329] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368332] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368335] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368340] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368343] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368381] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368386] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368389] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368393] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368397] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368400] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368439] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368443] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368447] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368450] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368454] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368458] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368497] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368501] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368505] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368508] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368512] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368515] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368554] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368558] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368562] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
[    0.368565] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180810/dswload2-316)
[    0.368569] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20180810/psobject-221)
[    0.368572] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode OpcodeName unavailable (20180810/psloop-543)
```

Scary at first glance, but sometimes my PC would start without problems. The thing is, that while my PC it's working I can see the battery level...etc, so that means ACPI it's working (I don't exactly know what's ACPI, just the basics from what I could get reading some information).

I've read that basically ACPI is like an interface between the BIOS/UEFI and the OS, to monitor power related stuff like battery level, or to send signals of suspend, shutdown...etc, to different components of the system.

The thing is, even if the ACPI is working, I know I'm still getting those errors, and for example I can't suspend my PC properly or hibernate...etc. These are problems, but the real deal is that sometimes when my PC is booting and it's getting those messages, It would freeze in that screen, with the errors. And I can't do anything, just press the power button, and sometimes turning on and off until it boots works.

Why does this happens? How can I solve it? I've read that maybe upgrading the BIOS could solve these errors, but I haven't yet tried it.

I'm using this laptop to study systems administration and networking so, I'd appreciate any kind of help ^^.

**EDIT 1**
[This link](https://jubilacionefectiva.com/acpi-error-una-tonteria-de-gnulinux-que-me-ha-vuelto-loco/) minimizes the chances of me having to turn off and on until it works sometimes.
Even tho, I'll try what the first comment said.

Comment: Please try installing the latest available kernel, 5.8.10.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Following [this link](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel) I was able to check the latest kernel available on Debian. In my case, I have installed "5.7.0-0.bpo.2-amd64". Not the latest, but now it works! I can lock my screen, suspend, hibernate...without any issues! Past year I was freaked out with this bug, but I'm glad they fixed it. Would you be so kind to create an answer to my question, so that way I can select it as what was my solution to the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an [issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199295) in old kernel releases, ostensibly it has been fixed in the most recent ones. Debian, because of its policy however features a relatively old kernel which is affected by the bug.

Please try installing the latest available stable kernel.